# Turning off OGNL warnings in Struts 2

Tags: java, xml, struts2, warnings, ognl

I am trying to turn off the following warning message

```
OgnlValueStac W com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn Error setting expression 'checkboxidentifyer' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@518b518b'
```

I have tried putting the following in my `log4j.xml` file

```
<logger name="log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2" >
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
<logger name="log4j.logger.com.opensymphony" >
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
<logger name="ognl.OgnlException" >
  <level value="ERROR" />
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger" >
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
<logger name="ognl.OgnlRuntime" >
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

I have also tried adding

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

to my `struts.xml` file. Also I have tried adding the following to the `interceptor-stack` section of the `struts.xml` file

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="excludeParams">.*?checkbox.*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

**My questions are:**

1. Did I do a miss configuration?
2. How do you disable the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `excludeParams` is a property of the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) and should be referenced like this

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="params.excludeParams">.*?checkbox.*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Note, if you use `interceptor-ref` tag on the action then it overrides the default interceptor stack and applicable only to this action config. For common usage consider creating a custom interceptor stack and make it default for any action configuration.

You can set a logging level for interceptors and OGNL. Using `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl=ERROR
```

Comment: I tried the change to the param name, and I also tried adding the new log4j.properties (we did not have one of those since we are using the xml configuration instead) and still I am getting the warning message.  And yes we are over riding the defualt interceptor-stack.

Comment: Let me also note I have tried adding those identifers to the log4j.xml file too, adding 
<logger name="log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor" >
and
 <logger name="log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl" >
to it, using the same body for the logger tag as I used in the question above.

Comment: Also add `<level value="ERROR">`.

Comment: I do have that in the file, both entries follow this formula <logger name="log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl" >
    <level value="ERROR" />
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </logger>

Comment: playing off of your anser about the location of the excludeParams, I moved it out of the <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"> section and into the <interceptor-ref name="params"> and that is what finally fixed the issue.

Comment: You said that referenced `defaultStack`, if you reference a stack then properties of the underlying interceptor are set using interceptor name prefix. Playing you off or on doesn't matter if this question helped you to solve your problem you should mark it as accepted. If you are new to SO you can read http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly sovled the error, while I had (as seen in the question above the param in the defaultStack interceptor-ref, when I moved the param to the interceptor-ref name params it removed the error

```
<interceptor-stack name="new_default_stack">
  <interceptor-ref name="params">
  <param name="paramNameMaxLength">250</param>
  <param name="excludeParams">.*?checkbox.*</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="timeActions"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">

  </interceptor-ref>
  <interceptor-ref name="userProfile"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="valueStackManipulator"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="actionHistoryRecorder"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

it was the location of the excludeParams that needed to be changed.